# Multipage Lookups - Update and Save

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a search function that opens up a user form (`FrmRecordDetails`) with the ID (`txtFnumber`) referenced at the top, it contains multipage userforms.

Now what I want it to is, when it opens up, is lookup and fill all the textboxes relating to the`Fnumber`. The reference spreadsheet is static so will not grow or contract and the Unique ID is in column A. i just want to fill each corresponding text-box, in each multipage tab from the row that has the unique ID.

Also when the user has updated I want to be able to overwrite the record back to the sheet.

Comment: What methods have you tried so far? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few bkookup on initialize tutorials/ functions but nothing happens. No error messages. Just would like to know the general way to reference a userform text box on multipage to search a sheet, column A to return the corresponding values.

Also to return them. Im pretty green with vba/userform stuff